# Can't login after installing Craft CMS 3

Tags: users, emails, login

I just installed Craft CMS 3 and I tried logging in as my admin user but it's not working. I enter the correct login information and nothing happens. I tried the reset password option but never got the email for some reason. Anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Does the login button turn red when you've typed enough? Craft might not have access to all of its javascript?

Comment: @kr37 Yes the login button turns red. I don't have JavaScript errors.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're not getting the message, "Invalid username or password", you're literally getting no message or action at all?

Comment: @TimKnight Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1):

It was a permission issue. I used the command below on the entire craft folder to get this to work:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 craft/
```

The logs were saying that it didn't have permissions to open many files.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is struggling with this: For development purposes I usually install Craft taking a subdomain. So my base domain "name.com" has an SSL certificate, the subdomain "sub.name.com" doesn't - that's causing the same problem. Just add a SSL certificate to the subdomain aswell and it should be working fine. Hope it's helping someone some day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting `[error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission. in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:218` on web.log

This worked for me:

1. clearing cookies on chrome `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`
2. then cleared caches  `craft clear-caches/all`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems after installing Craft CMS 3. I have been able to resolve it by adding write permissions to all directories in the storage directory. Just issue `sudo chmod 777 -R storage`. 
Then I could login to the admin page.

Comment: Requisite permissions disclaimer: Please be careful when fully opening permissions, _especially_ if you are in any kind of shared environment.